# PHP dictionary widget not working

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing

I'm trying to create a dictionary widget in which I implement Dictionary.com's API.  I have created an html form which contains a textbox & submit button.  I'm trying to write code which will emulate a dictionary search.  The code isn't working, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the PHP code I am using:

```
    <?php

  $vid = "<I ENTER THE VID HERE AS A STRING>";

  $url = "http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001?vid=" . $vid . "&q=" . $_POST['dictionary_search'] . "&type=define&site=dictionary";

  // initialize curl + store in a variable
  $ch = curl_init();

  // configure cURL
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  echo $result;
?>
```

I have php-curl enabled.  The API that I am using can be found here http://developer.dictionary.com/.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: is data returned as JSON ?

Comment: the data is returned as xml

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/path/here');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);

$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($retValue);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

## Method 2

```
$json_url  ='https://exampleurl';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$results =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

$xml = simplexml_load_string($results);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Two questions:  Could I place the following url into the download_page function? http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001?vid=<VID>&q=hello&type=define&site=dictionary

Comment: Second question:  I don't know the exact structure of the xml data, so how can I view all of the xml?

Comment: In your first example, it looks as if the code only works if you know what the xml is comprised of.

Comment: I've tried using your first example code, but I received an error:  Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name.  It says the error is for the line with $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($retValue);